# C# Linq Table query to count the non-matching entries

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am quite new to this, I am running two SQL queries and I am creating two separate data tables, `DataTable1` and `DataTable2`.

I am applying some linq criteria to `DataTable1` and creating another data table from that, which is `DataTable3`.

```
var Query3 = from table1 in DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
             where table1.Field<DateTime>("DateTime") <= Yday
             where table1.Field<string>("StockCode").Contains("-CA") && !(table1.Field<string>("StockCode").Contains("-CAB")) ||
                   table1.Field<string>("StockCode").Contains("-CM") ||
                   table1.Field<string>("StockCode").Contains("-LP")
             select table1;      

DataTable DataTable3 = Query3.CopyToDataTable()
```

Now I would write another query to do the following.

Both data tables have a column `JobNumber`. I would like to query `DataTable3` in DataTable 2 to count the rows that have similar JobNumber entries. Below is what I am doing but I am not getting the correct count.

```
int count = (from table3 in DataTable3.AsEnumerable()
             join table2 in DataTable2.AsEnumerable() on table2.Field<string>("JobNumber") equals table3.Field<string>("JobNumber")
             where table2.Field<string>("JobNumber") == table3.Field<string>("JobNumber")
             select table2).Count();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a cartesian join and counting its result, was that what you indented ? Also in your linq your Join expression and where expression is same (where is redundant). It is not clear what you really want to count. Probably you instead wanted to count those in DataTable2 where JobNumbers exists in DataTable3?:

```
var jobNumbers = (from r in DataTable3.AsEnumerable()
                 select r.Field<string>("JobNumber")).ToList();
var count = (from r in DataTable2.AsEnumerable()
             where jobNumbers.Contains( r.Field<string>("JobNumber") )
             select r).Count();
```

As a side note, it would be much easier if you used Linq To SQL instead (rather than Linq To DataSet).

Comment: Above mentioned works Yeah, Re-writing the code to do Direct Linq to sql.